# Use Variable for XML Attribute's Key?

Tags: xml, scala

I failed to use a variable within the key of an XML Node's attribute:

```
val x="foo"

scala> <A ${x}="bippy"></A>
<console>:1: error: in XML literal: '>' expected instead of '$'
<A ${x}="bippy"></A>
   ^
```

In short, I was looking for an output XML `Node` that equaled:

`<A foo="bippy"></A>`, i.e., where the `foo` replaced the `x` variable in the above, non-working attempt.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is supported. The opposite side of the equals sign is supported though: <A bippy={x}></A> will get you close. XML literal interpolation drops the $.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to accomplish is not allowed.

This should do the trick, although it is less elegant and less readable than your attempt:

```
val x = "foo"
scala.xml.XML.loadString(s"""<A $x="bippy" ></A>""")
```

`loadString` just creates a Node element out of a string.